# how to remove a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'm trying to remove a div using javascript, the div I'm trying to remove:

```
<div class="popover fade left in" style="top: -76.5px; left: -404px; display: block;">
```

The code I am using to try to remove it:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document(getElementByClassName('popover').remove());" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Close</a>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: While the general question is a duplicate, you can actually do exactly what you wanted pretty easily with `onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('popover')[0].remove()"`. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kh3r9b07/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `remove` jQuery function, you need to call it on a jQuery object. `getElementByClassName` returns a plain DOM element. Use the jQuery selector `$` to select the element and wrap it in a jQuery object, and then call `.remove` on it:

```
$('.popover').remove();
```

If you're using the plain JavaScript `.remove()`, you need to call it on a single DOM element, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Try this:

```
getElementsByClassName('popover')[0].remove()
```

Comment: Actually, it returns a `NodeList` containing a bunch of plain DOM elements.

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this:

Comment: I completely forgot that .remove() was jQuery, I'll need to get some sleep soon ehe, thanks for the help though, got it working now.

Comment: @KristoferAronSverrisson: `.remove()` also exists in modern browsers in the native API, but you can't call it on a collection. It must be on individual nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="removePopovers()" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Close</a>
```

Javascript

```
removePopovers = function () {
    var popovers =  document.querySelectorAll('.popover');
    for (var i = 0; i < popovers.length; i++) {
         popovers[i].outerHTML= ''; 
    }
}
```

This selects all elements with the `popover` class and sets their`outerHTML` to nothing, which removes the divs.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r7acqmy/)</kbd>

Comment: This wouldn't work too well for me seeing that it can occur that more than 1 popover is on the page, I just needed a single button that closes them all.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a way to remove all of them.